# Telerik Control multi language support for Windows Form

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, telerik

I didn't find any property to enable Multi-Language support for ASP.NET windows Form.

In web application there is property as shown below

```
<telerik:RadSpell ID="spell1" runat="server" ControlToCheck="textBox1" 
     SupportedLanguages="en-US,English,fr-FR,French"></telerik:RadSpell>
```

Please confirm telerik control support multi language directly or need to created language file for support.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multi-language telerik windows forms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12762540/multi-language-telerik-windows-forms)

Comment: @Piyush Both are different question.

Comment: Which technology do you use - ASP.NET or Windows forms? And what precisely you want to localize?